# Bound for series of probabilities of events

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I am attempting to prove that a sequence of events occurs infinitely often with probability 0, similarly to Borel-Cantelli. I know the series of probabilities of set differences converges. This is what I came up with, using Boole's inequality:
$$\mathbb{P}(E_n\text{ i.o.}) \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m=n}^\infty \mathbb{P}(E_m) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m=n}^\infty \mathbb{P}(E_m) - \mathbb{P}(E_m \cap E_{m-1})=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{m=n}^\infty \mathbb{P} (E_m \setminus E_{m-1}) = 0$$
Is this a valid approach ?

**Edit**
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(E_{n+1} \setminus E_n) < \infty$$ and $$\mathbb{P}(E_n) \rightarrow 0$$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ are given.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by "the series of probabilities of set differences converges."

Comment: I added details and corrected the inequality

Comment: @Tab1e yes since $$\mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E_k \right) = 0$$

Comment: No. Where do you obtain $\mathbb{P} \left(\cap_{k=1}^\infty E_k\right)$? If you put it as an assumption, you still need to add that the events $E_k$ are independent because this assumption does not imply that $\mathbb{P} (E_m \cap E_{m-1})=0$.

Comment: While $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap E_k) = 0$, I don't see why this implies $\mathbb{P}(E_k \cap E_{k-1}) = 0$.  You could think of a situation where $\mathbb{P}(E_k) = \frac 1k$, for example.

Comment: So the condition on the limit is enough to conclude? Is there a need to use the convergence of the series of set differences?

Comment: @Tab1e The fact $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E_k) = 0$ comes from the fact that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(E_k) = 0$.  I agree with the rest of your comment, and that fact should be pointed out before using it, but it is possible to conclude it without any extra assumptions

Comment: @SimonCello94 No, the condition on the limit is not enough to conclude it.  The example where $\mathbb{P}(E_k) = \frac 1k$ and the $E_k$ are independent shows you need more.

Comment: @user6247850 Oh yeah I see your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the "disjoint-ification" trick to find that
\begin{align*}
\bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k = E_n \cup \left[\bigcup_{k=n+1}^\infty \left( E_k \setminus \left(\bigcup_{j=n}^k E_j \right) \right) \right] \subseteq E_n \cup \left( \bigcup_{k=n+1}^\infty (E_k \setminus E_{k-1}) \right),
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k \right) &\le \mathbb{P}\left( E_n \cup \left( \bigcup_{k=n+1}^\infty (E_k \setminus E_{k-1}) \right) \right) \\
&\le \mathbb{P}(E_n) + \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{k=n+1}^\infty (E_k \setminus E_{k-1}) \right) \\
&\le \mathbb{P}(E_n) + \sum_{k=n}^\infty \mathbb{P}(E_k \setminus E_{k-1}).
\end{align*}
By hypothesis, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(E_n) = 0$, and since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(E_k \setminus E_{k-1}) < \infty$ we also have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty \mathbb{P}(E_k \setminus E_{k-1}) = 0$.  Therefore we conclude $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k \right) = 0$ and so $$ \mathbb{P}\left(\limsup E_n \right) = \mathbb{P}\left( \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k \right) \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}\left( \bigcup_{k=n}^\infty E_k \right) = 0 $$
as desired.

Comment: Very clever, thanks!